# How to exclude a file from coverage report in Mocha and Nyc

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, nyc

I have a test setup configured with Mocha and nyc.

I'm trying to exclude a certain file from the report. So I tried this:

```
"nyc": {
    "exclude": [
      "./sites/modules/carousel-widget/",
    ]
  },
```

And it actually seems to works because the overall percentage moves up (from 48% to 60%). However, I can still see the file under file section in the report as if the above lines do not have any effect on this.

[image]

[image]
I even tried the following. But it didn't work.

```
"test:coverage": "APOS_TEST=1 nyc --reporter=html mocha --file ./test/lib/setup.js \"test/**/*.{spec,test}.js\"  --ignore ./sites/modules/carousel-widget/",
```

How can I be able to get this excluded in the reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is this:

```
"nyc": {
   "exclude": ["**/sites/modules/carousel-widget/*",
    ]
  },
```

Not sure why giving the exact path doesn't work. Wildcard at the start does the job though.